# How to write this "algorithm" with a lot of IF statements easier?

Tags: algorithm

So basically I have a list of cases for example if a, e and i all have a value of 1 something should happen but the list is big and idk want to spam else if statements

if a, b, c

if a, d, g

if a, e, i

if b, e, h

if c, e, g

if c, f, i

if d, e, f

if g, h, i

so i dont want to do it like this:

```
if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) {
   console.log("Hello");
} else if (a == 1 && d == 1 && g == 1) {
   console.log("Hello");
} else if (b == 1 && e == 1 && h == 1) {
   console.log("Hello")
} ETC ETC ETC
```

Comment: you have 7 boolean variables? it's very rare as a thing, I would say that you might have other issues before this to end up in this situation, because AFAIK considering only 3 variables each time, you have around 200 combinations

Comment: The combinations I listed are the only ones I need

Comment: You can certainly combine the booleans into a single 7-bit number, and then use a `switch` statement (or the equivalent in whatever language you're using). But at the end of the day, you still have 8 blocks of code that need to be executed. If those blocks are big, you may want to implement each block as a separate function.

Comment: Is the processing the same in all cases ??

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add a layer of abstraction and make your code a bit more idiomatic at the same time. Let's assume that in this example we have an Rails model object named "alphabet" and it has attributes/columns for each letter of the alphabet. See the below pseudocode for a way to make your code a bit more readable:

```
class Alphabet < ApplicationRecord
  def what_should_i_do
    if is_first_state
      puts "Hey"
    elsif is_second_state
      puts "Ho"
    elsif is_third_state
      puts "Hum"
    end
  end

  def is_first_state
    a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1
  end

  def is_second_state
    a == 1 && d == 1 && g == 1
  end

  def is_third_state
    b == 1 && e == 1 && h == 1
  end
end
```

Also, sometimes when I end up writing long if/else statements like this, it can be an opportunity to use inheritance to solve the problem. I don't have a good example that I can think of in relation to the example you provided, but I've found that deferring logic to a child instance can move complexity to the correct places and complexity in the correct place often makes for less complexity.

Also, if you truly have a list of 1s and 0s, you might want to consider interacting with that data as an array instead of as individual variables. Once again, it depends on the specifics of what you are working with and what you are really trying to do. The provided example is super-generalized so it's difficult to give a helpful answer.